# Why are my while parameters not being acknowledged

Tags: c++, if-statement, parameters, do-while

Hangman game

it is not stopping the loop when the parameters are met
is there a different way to do this
or am I coding something wrong
sorry I am a noob at coding started a week ago
thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

string sword = "---";
string swordans = "nhs";
char guess;
int guessnum;
guessnum = 0;
int incguessnum;
incguessnum = 0;


while ((((guessnum < 7) && (incguessnum < 6)) || **(sword == swordans)**))
{
    cout<<"Please guess a letter"<<endl;           (   /\  )
    cin>>guess;                                    (   ||  ) 
                                                   (   ||  ) 
    if (guess == 'n')                          (pver here it is not stopping
    {                                           the loop when the replaced
        guessnum ++;                            sword = swordans string)

        cout<<"You have guessed "<< guessnum <<" time(s)"<< endl;
        cout<<"Correct"<<endl;
        sword.replace(0,1,"n");
        cout<<sword<<endl;
    }

    else if (guess == 'h')
    {
        guessnum ++;
        cout<<"You have guessed "<< guessnum <<" time(s)"<< endl;
        cout<<"Correct"<<endl;
        sword.replace(1,1,"h");
        cout<<sword<<endl;
    }
    else if (guess == 's')
    {
        guessnum ++;
        cout<<"You have guessed "<< guessnum <<" time(s)"<< endl;
        cout<<"Correct"<<endl;
        sword.replace(2,1,"s");
        cout<<sword<<endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        guessnum ++;
        cout<<"You have guessed "<< guessnum <<" time(s)"<< endl;
        incguessnum++;
        cout<<"Incorrect"<<endl;
        if (incguessnum == 1)
        {
            cout<<" o"<<endl;
        }
        else if (incguessnum == 2)
        {
            cout<<" o"<<endl;
            cout<<" |"<<endl;
        }
        else if (incguessnum == 3)
        {
            cout<<" o"<<endl;
            cout<<" |"<<endl;
            cout<<" |"<<endl;
        }else if (incguessnum == 4)
        {
            cout<<" o"<<endl;
            cout<<" |"<<endl;
            cout<<" |"<<endl;
            cout<<"/"<<endl;
        }else if (incguessnum == 5)
        {
            cout<<" o"<<endl;
            cout<<" |"<<endl;
            cout<<" |"<<endl;
            cout<<"/ \\"<<endl;
        }else if (incguessnum == 6)
        {
            cout<<"  o"<<endl;
            cout<<"  |"<<endl;
            cout<<"--|"<<endl;
            cout<<" / \\"<<endl;

        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<"  o"<<endl;
            cout<<"  |"<<endl;
            cout<<"--|--"<<endl;
            cout<<" / \\"<<endl;
        }

    }
}


system ("pause");
return(0);
}
```

Comment: It'd be preferable to post your code in compilable form, instead of covered in ascii art. Use `//`-style comments if necessary

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((((guessnum < 7) && (incguessnum < 6)) || (sword == swordans)))
```

This loop will continue while number of guesses is less than 7 and incorrect guesses is less than 6. It will ALSO continue while sword is equal to swordans.

You could replace it with this for the desired effect:

```
while(guessnum < 7 && incguessnum < 6 && sword != swordans)
```

It also reads much more neatly ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to have the loop terminate when `sword == swordans` then you need to adjust your condition to `&& (sword != swordans)` instead. You only want to continue looping if the player hasn't used up all of their guesses AND if they haven't solved the puzzle.

As it stands right now, *your loop will continue infinitely once the strings are equal* -- surely not what you intended.

Your condition is being "acknowledged" accurately, but since the condition is wrong you don't see the desired behavior.